# Need to run connectedCheck on app testing service. Which provider? Device Farm/Test Labs/Xamarin?

Tags: automated-tests, android-espresso, cucumber-jvm, aws-device-farm, firebase-test-lab

We are experimenting with test automation and have found that cucumber-jvm/espresso fits the best.  Our next issue is finding a testing service that supports the framework.  To run the tests we are currently running 'gradlew connectedCheck' at the command line but from what I have read, AWS Device Farm doesn't support cucumber-jvm/espresso.  Any service should work, so long as it supports cucumber-jvm and has a variety of physical devices to test on.

I am hoping that someone out here has experience with this and knows where we should look.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use Cucumber along with Espresso in that case? You can always implement an entire test suite without the need of Cucumber. All you need is a good reporting tool to report you the passes and failures. There are plenty of solutions out there -- I would recommend using something like [Spoon](https://github.com/square/spoon) or [Composer](https://github.com/gojuno/composer) to run your tests in parallel on multiple devices or emulators or a combination of both. Both of these tools provide decent reporting. As far as a device farm is considered, AWS will support that.